# Wieso schreibt man „Süsses“ gross?

Tags: capitalization, nominalization

„Ich habe etwas Süsses gegessen.“

Wieso ist in dem Fall „Süsses“ grossgeschrieben bzw. wieso ist es dann ein Substantiv?

Was ist der Unterschied zu einem „normalen“ Substantiv?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es handelt sich dabei um eine Substantivierung. Das lässt sich sehr einfach an dem Signalwort etwas erkennen. Der Unterschied zu einem "normalen" Substantiv ist, dass süß normalerweise ein Adjektiv ist, in dieser Form dann allerdings zu einem Substantiv gemacht wird.

Siehe auch hier: [Studienkreis | Substantivierungen](https://www.studienkreis.de/deutsch/substantivierungen-verben-adjektive-regeln-uebungen/)

Comment: Allerdings würdes "Süßes" auch ohne "etwas" großgeschschrieben. Anders wenn es nicht flektiert wäre, dann wäre es ein Adverb: *Ich habe süß gegessen.*

Comment: Vielen Dank für die genaue Erklärung!

Answer (score 0):

Eigentlich ist es ganz einfach:

- Im Deutschen wird das jeweils erste Wort eines Satz mit großem Anfangsbuchstaben geschrieben, und es werden auch alle Substantive mit großem Anfangsbuchstaben geschrieben. Alle anderen Wörter werden durchgehend klein geschrieben.

Den Beginn eines Satzes erkennt man relativ leicht (obwohl es auch da Problemfälle gibt). Das eigentliche Problem ist aber, zu erkennen, welche Wörter Substantive sind.

Da gibt es aber einen Trick, der gar nicht schwer ist. Man muss ihn nur kennen und anwenden: Wenn vor dem fraglichen Wort ein Determinativ steht, oder wenn man dort ein Determinativ ergänzen kann, ist es ein Substantiv. Wenn nicht, dann nicht.

Ein anderer Name für *Determinativ* ist *Artikelwort.* Dazu gehören:

- Artikel (*der, die, das, dem, den, des, ein, eine, eines, einem, einen*)
- Demonstrativpronomen (Formen von *dieser*, *jener* und *der*, z.B. *dessen*)
- Possessivpronomen (*mein, dein,* usw.)
- Indefinitpronomen (*kein, viele, alle, etwas,* usw.)
- Zahlwörter (*ein, zwei, drei,* usw.)
- In Fragesätzen auch Fragedeterminativa (Formen von *wessen, welchen, was für ein, wie viele,* usw.)

In deinem Beispielsatz steht vor dem fraglichen Wort ein Indefinitpronomen (nämlich *»etwas«*), also ein Determinativ, und daher muss das Wort dahinter ein Substantiv sein, und aus diesem Grund muss man es großschreiben.

Wenn es dieses Determinativ nicht gäbe, wäre *Süßes* trotzdem ein Substantiv, denn die Regel sagt ja, dass man auch versuchen kann ein Determinativ vor dem Wort einzufügen. Und wenn das klappt, hat das Wort den Substantiv-Test bestanden und muss groß geschrieben werden.

---

Was ist der Unterschied zu einem „normalen“ Substantiv?

Grammatisch gibt es gar keinen Unterschied, weil dieses Wort ein Substantiv ist.

Unterschiedlich ist nur, dass es ein Substantiv ist, das von einem Wort aus einer anderen Wortart abgeleitet ist, in diesem Fall von einem Adjektiv. Aus diesem Grund nennt man so ein Wort leider auch **substantiviertes Adjektiv.** Diese Bezeichnung sollte man aber schnell wieder vergessen, denn das Wort *Süßes* in deinem Satz ist **kein** Adjektiv. Es ist ein Substantiv mit adjektivischer Herkunft.

Dass sich durch Ableitungen die Wortart ändert, ist sehr häufig, und Substantive sind da nur eine von vielen Wortarten, die an diesem Spiel teilnehmen. In Wahrheit ist es oft sogar gar nicht möglich festzustellen, welches Wort das ursprüngliche und welches das abgeleitete ist. Wenn man das Paar *»die Pflanze« (Substantiv) »pflanzen« (Verb)* betrachtet, könnte ich ohne genauere Recherchen nicht sagen, welches der beiden Wörter das ursprünglichere ist und welches das abgeleitete. Daher sollte man sich darüber auch gar nicht all zu viele Gedanken machen, weil das Ergebnis einer solchen Recherche zwar vielleicht andere interessante Erkenntnisse bringt, aber bei der Frage der Groß-/Kleinschreibung überhaupt nicht weiterhilft.

Einen Unterschied möchte ich trotzdem erwähnen:

Oft steht ein Substantiv, das aus einem attributiv verwendeten Adjektiv entstanden ist, alleine anstelle des Wortes dessen Substantiv es war. In diesem Fall richtet sich das Geschlecht dieses abgeleiteten Substantiv nach dem Geschlecht des ursprünglichen Wortes.

> vorher: Der große Mann trinkt Tee. Die große Frau trägt Handschuhe.
>   nachher: Der Große trinkt Tee. Die Große trägt Handschuhe.

In solchen Fällen ist es auch möglich, das Adjektiv weiterhin als Adjektiv (und somit als Attribut eine Substantivs) zu interpretieren, dessen Bezugswort aber weggelassen wurde, weil es sich eindeutig aus dem Kontext ergibt.

> Auch erlaubt: Ein großer und ein kleiner Mann sitzen an einem Tisch. Der große trinkt Tee. Der kleine liest eine Zeitung.